# Selecting Records Between 2 dates in ms access database

Tags: c#, sql, date, ms-access

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t_Final_Out
WHERE repo_dt BETWEEN #19/01/2017# AND #01/06/2017#;
```

`repo_dt` is `date/time` field

When i'm executing this query I get only records on "19/01/2017"

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it returns anything.  When using `between`, the first comparand should be less than the second.  With "standard" settings, your dates would be '2017-01-19' and '2017-01-06'.

I think your problem is the date format itself.  MS Access seems to prefer mm/dd/yyyy, so I think you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_Final_Out
WHERE repo_dt BETWEEN #01/19/2017# AND #06/01/2017#;
```